# Spring JMS transaction rollback - message dequeued off ActiveMQ

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-transactions, spring-jms

I have a simple Spring Boot application(Spring Boot Version 1.5.3.RELEASE) for consuming JMS Messages off an ActiveMQ(version 5.14.5) Queue.

I want the messages to be consumed in a JMS transaction. If there is an exception during message consumption, I expect transaction to be rolled back and message not to be dequeued(taken off message queue). I can see transaction being rolled back in Spring logs, however the message is still dequeued from ActiveMQ queue(after six re delivery attempts).

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Here is the application code:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
public class SpringJmsDemoApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringJmsDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory));
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        configurer.configure(defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory, connectionFactory);
        return defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
    }
}

@Component
```

public class Receiver {

```
@JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory")
@Transactional
public void receiveMessage(String email) {
    System.out.println("Received <" + email + ">");
    throw new RuntimeException("nooo");
}
```

}

Here is the log:

```
2017-05-24 09:51:59.865 DEBUG 8972 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] o.s.j.connection.JmsTransactionManager   : Created JMS transaction on Session [ActiveMQSession {id=ID:D6C0B8467A518-58248-1495590693980-1:32:1,started=false} java.lang.Object@65d647cd] from Connection [ActiveMQConnection 
2017-05-24 09:51:59.867 DEBUG 8972 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Received message of type [class org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage] from consumer [ActiveMQMessageConsumer { value=ID:D6C0B8467A518-58248-1495590693980-1:32:1:1, started=true }] of transactional session [ActiveMQSession {id=ID:D6C0B8467A518-58248-1495590693980-1:32:1,started=true} java.lang.Object@65d647cd]
2017-05-24 09:51:59.867 DEBUG 8972 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Rolling back transaction because of listener exception thrown: org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.anz.markets.springjmsdemo.Receiver.receiveMessage(java.lang.String)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: nooo
2017-05-24 09:51:59.867  WARN 8972 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.

org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.anz.markets.springjmsdemo.Receiver.receiveMessage(java.lang.String)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: nooo
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:112) ~[spring-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:69) ~[spring-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:721) ~[spring-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:681) ~[spring-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651) ~[spring-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317) [spring-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:235) [spring-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166) [spring-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158) [spring-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055) [spring-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: nooo
    at com.anz.markets.springjmsdemo.Receiver.receiveMessage(Receiver.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:180) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:112) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:104) ~[spring-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2017-05-24 09:51:59.868 DEBUG 8972 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] o.s.j.connection.JmsTransactionManager   : Transactional code has requested rollback
2017-05-24 09:51:59.868 DEBUG 8972 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] o.s.j.connection.JmsTransactionManager   : Initiating transaction rollback
2017-05-24 09:51:59.868 DEBUG 8972 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] o.s.j.connection.JmsTransactionManager   : Rolling back JMS transaction on Session [ActiveMQSession {id=ID:D6C0B8467A518-58248-1495590693980-1:32:1,started=true} java.lang.Object@65d647cd]
```

Comment: It appears to an ActiveMQ feature where in a message is moved to a default dead letter queue after message failed redelivery attempts and rollback of the transaction.

Comment: I checked ActiveMQ broker logs and can see the broker "rollbacks" the message, but the effect of rollback is message being dequeued rather than staying enqueued. I can't see any default dead letter channel queue on the admin console.

Comment: Is it possible to configure ActiveMQ Broker so that the message is not routed to a Dead Letter Queue but stays enqueued on the original queue in case of transaction rollback? In scenario where application persistent store(db) is down, I would prefer the message to stay enqueued rather than being moved to a deal letter queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ActiveMQ message re-delivery documentation, the messages, which failed to be delivered, will go to the dead letter queue (http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html):

"The default Dead Letter Queue in ActiveMQ is called ActiveMQ.DLQ; all un-deliverable messages will get sent to this queue and this can be difficult to manage. So, you can set an `individualDeadLetterStrategy` in the destination policy map of the `activemq.xml` configuration file, which allows you to specify a specific dead letter queue prefix for a given queue or topic. You can apply this strategy using wild card if you like so that all queues get their own dead-letter queue, as is shown in the example below"

Please, extend you `activemq.xml` with `individualDeadLetterStrategy` to the queue.